# Installing Visual Studio 2017 along side 2013 stopping IIS 7 website from loading HTTPS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-7, ssl-certificate, visual-studio-2017

I have been using Visual Studio 2013 Professional. Yesterday I decided to also install Visual Studio 2017 (after its release) along side for evaluation.

All went well until I realized that my existing IIS7 hosted website was not accessible via HTTPS.

I tried messing around with certificates in mmc and browsers etc with no luck.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all that I needed to do was to delete my existing 443 binding on my website and then simply re-add it again!

[image]